# read HITRAN file format

Tags: r

Taking [this file](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/Updated/01_hit09.par) as an example, I'm trying to read the data in a data.frame. From [the doc](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/Download/HITRAN04paper.pdf) (pdf file, table 1), it follows some fortran convention. I tried the following with little success:

```
dir <- "Uncompressed-files/"
file <- "01_hit09.par"

delim <- c("I2", "I1", "F12.6", "E10.3", "E10.3", "F5.4", "F5.4", 
"F10.4", "F4.2", "F8.6", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "6I1", "6I2", 
"A1", "F7.1", "F7.1")
test <- read.fortran(paste0(dir, file), delim)

test <- read.fwf(paste0(dir, file),
                 c(2, 1, 12, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 4, 8,
                   15, 15, 15, 15, 6, 12, 1, 7, 7))
```

Any tips to specify the correct format?

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what is wrong with what you get for `test`?

Comment: Your `read.fwf` version works for me. (Except that read.fwf is really rather slow.) There are faster versions around, e.g. `fast.read.fwf` in package `mvbutils`.

Comment: @Andrie: `read.fwf` "works" but the format isn't specified correctly, so the output is incorrect.  Specifically, the 6 in front of `"6I1"` and `"6I2"` mean "repeat this format 6 times".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `?read.fortran`:

1. `"E"` is not a supported format.
2. "specifying 'd > 0' in the 'F' or 'D' format will shift
    the decimal 'd' places to the left, even if it is explicitly
    specified in the input file."

So change `"E"` to `"F"` and remove all the explicit decimal formats:

```
file <- "01_hit09.par"
delim <- c("I2", "I1", "F12", "F10", "F10", "F5", "F5", "F10", "F4", "F8",
           "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15", "6I1", "6I2", "A1", "F7", "F7")
(test <- read.fortran(file, delim, n=10))
```

UPDATE: Or specify the widths correctly and use `read.fwf`:

```
 test2 <- read.fwf(file, c(2,1,12,10,10,5,5,10,4,8,15,15,15,15,
                           rep(1,6),rep(2,6),1,7,7), as.is=TRUE)
```